# Using showModalDialog together with Selections

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to use the showModalDialog method to display a message to a user, which will also need to have two buttons, a "Yes" and "No" but unsure how to approach this method.

I am using IE8 and unsure how to declare this and how I need to assign this that will also cater for both "Yes" and "No" options.

If "No" is pressed, I basically want the showModalDialog closed, with no further action required by the user.

If "Yes" is pressed, I then want it to go off and call a JavaScript function.

I have looked online but I can't seem to find any examples relating to what I am after here.

I am seeking links to good examples that relates to my requirement above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - If you are using jQuery, then you would use it's powerfull **widget library** http://jqueryui.com

---

> - **DEMO:** http://so.devilmaycode.it/help-with-showmodaldialog-together-with-selections

**IMPLEMENTATION:**

```
$(function() {
  var external_data = "i'm outside the func";
    $('.show-modal-dialog').click(function(e) {
       var internal_data = "i'm inside the call";
       var a = this;
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#dialog-message").dialog({
            title: 'this is a modal dialog',
            modal: true,
            open: function(event, ui) {
              $(this).append(a.href); //append inside the Dialog it self
            },
            buttons: {
                'Yes': function() {
                    alert(a.href + ' ' + external_data + ' ' + internal_data);
                },
                'No': function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**BODY:**

```
<div id="dialog-message"><p>Lorem Ipsum Est</p></div>

<a class="show-modal-dialog" href="http://www.google.it">Show Modal Dialog</a>
```

Comment: thanks @aSeptik but have two further questions. 1) How would I pass any type of data into this dialog and 2) could you please provide an example of using showModalDialog as I'm not sure if I will go the jQuery way. Thanks.

Comment: thanks. With the showModalDialog, I need to pass a url into it, is this possible, if so, then how?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery.ui you, checkout this [sample](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation). If you don't want to use jquery.ui, take a look at [Block.UI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#dialog) plugin.